How to activate gitlab pages in a selfhosted gitlab instance?
What are all the attributes to set in gitlab.rb file to activate gitlab pages.
How to host the pages site on another sever other than the server where gitlab instance is running ?
I am confused with the online documentation on gitlab site, there seems to be no direct way to do it.

If you want your GitLab instance to run on multiple servers/nodes, you would have needed to make that decision when installing: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/reference_architectures/
What settings you need in your gitlab.rb file depends on your setup. There's no one answer, so you'd need to refer to https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/pages/
